# Should I use "who" twice in this sentence?

Tags: nouns, relative-clauses, lists

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> I'm a Turkish who is trying to learn Finnish, German and also wants to learn Russian.

Can I also say:

> I'm a Turkish who is trying to learn Finnish, German and **who** also wants to learn Russian.

Answer (score 2):

First, in English, the noun for Turkish nationality is *Turk*, not Turkish. Thus, *I am a Turk who is trying to learn...* See [the M-W dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turk). You can also say *Turkish person*. This is similar to the adjective *British*, which is not used as a noun, except in rare occasions.

Since you list only Finnish and German, it is better to use *and* to connect them rather than connect them only with a comma (,).

You can use the *who* in the second half of the sentence, or not--it's your choice.

Thus

> I am a Turk who is trying to learn Finnish and German and also wants to learn Russian.

and

> I am a Turk who is trying to learn Finnish and German and who also wants to learn Russian.

are correct. I prefer the second one, because the second use of *who* lends some stability to the sentence.

Comment: The predicates are in different tenses.  I'd also use that as an additional justification to provide each predicate with its own subject.

Comment: @VictorBazarov That's probably why I prefer the second sentence. Although it does come down to a matter of style and not grammar.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your objective. If you are aiming for a uniform list, repeating the *who* helps. If you want to emphasise learning Finnish and German, retain just the first *who*. If you want to emphasise learning Russian, retain just the second.

The repeated form "who is ... who is" emphasises structure. Have a look at this [link](http://grammar.about.com/od/developingparagraphs/a/cohrepetition.htm), which includes an example with a Turkish novelist.